# How can I add space between parentheses and string with Re library in Python?

Tags: python, python-re

I have 3 different strings and If there is no space between string and parentheses(If there is a escape, don't touch), I have to add space before and after parentheses.
It looks really complicated Re library for me and I couldn't figure out. Especially when I am using parentheses.

```
test = "example(test)"
test2 = "example(test)example"
test3 = "(test)example"
```

I have to do all of them in one re function.

```
result = re.sub(r"Some code for all of them","Space here",test or test2 or test3)

print(result)
```

### Output

```
test = "example (test)"
test2 = "example (test) example"
test3 = "(test) example"
```

I know it looks a lot but there should be no space at the end of the sentence.

Comment: That's not your output from any code you wrote, your regex and replacement aren't your actual code, and there is no space at the end of the strings in your output, which you claim is your problem. Provide a real [MCVE] demonstrating your problem, not just handwavey explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need these regexes

```
re.sub(r'(\D{1})([(])',r'\1 (',test)
```

For test

```
re.sub(r'(\D)([)]){1}',r'\1) ',test2 or test3)
```

For test2 and test3

Answer (score 4):

This is one approach

```
import re

test = "example(test)"
test2 = "example(test)example"
test3 = "(test)example"
test4 = "example (test) example"

for i in [test, test2, test3, test4]:
    print(re.sub(r"[^\S]?(\(.*?\))[^\S]?", r" \1 ", i).strip())
```

**Output:**

```
example (test)
example (test) example
(test) example
example (test) example
```

Answer (score 2):

You could limit the search of `(` to all places except beginning of string, and `)` to all places except end of string:

```
result = re.sub(r"\)(?!$)",") ", re.sub(r"(?<!^)\("," (", some_test))
```

To cope with possible existing white spaces:

```
result = re.sub(r"\)(?!\s)(?!$)",") ", re.sub(r"(?<!^)(?<!\s)\("," (", some_test))
```

Comment: But it will add one more space although there is space

Comment: It says "(If there is a scape, don't touch)". I hope you have an idea for it.

Comment: @MuratDemir - you are right :) fixed

Comment: Dude your's work same. Look at @Rakesh answer. It works clear

Answer (score 1):

Replace for the first bracket and thereafter the second one

```
import re

test = "example(test)"
test2 = "example(test)example"
test3 = "(test)example"

for_test = re.sub(r"\(","( ",test)
for_test2 = re.sub(r"\(","( ",test2)
for_test3 = re.sub(r"\(","( ",test3)


output_test = re.sub(r"\)"," )",for_test)
output_test2 = re.sub(r"\)"," )",for_test2)
output_test3 = re.sub(r"\)"," )",for_test3)
print(output_test)
print(output_test2)
print(output_test3)
```

Output

```
example( test )
example( test )example
( test )example
```

Comment: It is a long way of @gilad-green 's way